# Changing class variables by calling super

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it possible to change a derived class' variable from the super in C++?

(Using an example may make my question more clear..)

Say I have the following classes and functions:

```
class SuperClass                             // super class
{            
    int myClassVariable;

public:
    virtual void modify()
    {
        myClassVariable = 10;
    }  
};

class DerivedClass  : public SuperClass     // derived class
{            
    int myClassVariable;

public:
    void modify()
    {
        super::modify();
    }  
};
```

And if I do the following:

```
DerivedClass d;
d.modify();
```

Question: Who's `myClassVariable` gets modified to 10? The super class or the derived class?

(Thank you in advance for you patience and help.. hope my question isn't a stupid one!)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the super class, since the member is modified in the super class and a member can't be virtual, only methods can be virtual.

Also note that modify() isn't virtual in the derived class (with respect to the super class), it's only virtual to children of the derived class, since modify() wasn't declared virtual in the super class.

Comment: Thanks! I meant to have it declared as virtual in the super class.. :S

Comment: @developer: Though, for the answer to this question, it doesn't matter if it's declared virtual or not. :-) When you explicitly call `<class name>::func` you are making a non-virtual function call.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Ah.. I suppose if I had `SuperClass d = new DerivedClass(); d.modify();` would then make use of the virtual declaration right?

Comment: @developer: Nope, that was exactly my point :) But since you said you meant to write virtual in the super class in the first place, so yes it will make use of the virtual declaration :D

Comment: @Magnus: Thanks I think I understand now.. (new to c++ inheritance)

Comment: @developer: Anyone that says he finally understands c++ inheritance might be in for a treat ;) (Just kidding, but I believe that a lot of c++ programmers out there know exactly what I'm talking about)

Comment: @Magnus: I suppose what I meant was that I understand the answer to my question.. not that I understand everything about inheritance! I'm pretty sure I'll have many more questions down the road! lol! :D